# Back transform predict.gam() from nb link log model run?

Tags: predictive-models, generalized-additive-model, mgcv, link-function, back-transformation

I have model with 1 covariate. I would like to run y values from gam in another model. I used nb(log=link) in gam model. Because I used nb and link log in gam, do I need to back transform to use output from predict.gam() to match real values? I would like to run predicted in another model and to compare with other real data.

Simple model ex:

**gam model**

```r
model_a <- gam(species_count~ s(slope), data=dat,
               family=nb(link = "log"), method="ML")
```

**Use predict.gam to grab y values**

```r
speciesct_a <- predict.gam(model_a,type="response")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to do a further transformation to the response scale as you have already specified `type = "response"` in your call to `predict()`.

Note that you can't use the standard errors returned by adding `se.fit = TRUE` to your `predict()` call *if* you continue to use `type = "response"` because there's no easy way to do it once everything is transformed back to the response scale. If you do want to form confidence/credible intervals, use `type = "link", se.fit = TRUE` and then create the confidence/credible interval and then manually use `exp()` to back transform the fitted/predicted values and the interval to the response scale.

Or you could use my {gratia} package and its `fitted_values()` function which takes care of this for you and with `scale = "response"` would give you an interval on the response scale that has been created properly (following the brief steps I outlined above).

Comment: Thank you @GavingSimpson. Gratia package is seamless making it easy. When comparing predicted data in say 1-10 different model scenarios, does the K for a covariate remain the same for all 10 models to use AIC for model selection? And if to compare predicted models 1-10 vs. observed data models 1-10, should covariate terms have same K value to compare across the 20 models for both predicted and observed using AIC? For example: s(Temp, k=15), s(elevation, k=20). Should these two covariates have the  same K for all 20 models? Should a fixed K be determined for all models using gam.check() first?